# glob_fileinput: как прочитать все файлы один раз и найти нужное?

Tags: python

```
def One():
  duble = []
  for l in open("log.log"):
    duble.append(l)

  for i in set(duble):
    f = Two(i.rstrip())

def Two(*args):
  for fname in glob.glob('test*.txt'):
    for line in open(fname):
      if args[0]==line:
        retrun line
```

Вопрос, как в функции Two() прочитать все файлы один раз и в прочитанном найти нужное, а такой алгоритм работы, для каждой строки читает все файлы каждый раз.

Answer (score 1):

```
def log_read()
    with open('log.log') as fp:
        return frozenset([l.rstrip() for l in fp])

def log_search(logs):
    for file in glob.glob('test*.txt'):
        with open(file) as fp:
            for line in fp:
                if line in logs:
                    return line
```